# Save output of command to variable and print without using tee?

Tags: bash, shell-script

I am trying to find a method to save the output of a command to variable but also print it in real time. I initially found an example with `tee` that seemed to work;

```
VARIABLE=$(./build.sh | tee /dev/tty)
```

However the problem with this is that if I run it on a system with virtual console (i.e. git hub actions) I get an error `tee: /dev/tty: No such device or address`. I just want to find a way to save output to a variable and do a normal print in real time (i.e. just like echo, printf, etc.)

Comment: What is wrong with `printf '%s\n' "$VARIABLE"` just after?

Comment: I rather see it live, and I also have set `set -e -o pipefail` so if the build fails I will not get any outputs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could tee to stderr:

```
VARIABLE=$(./build.sh | tee /dev/stderr)
```

Answer (score 4):

The problem with using `/dev/tty` is it assumes that stdout was originally attached to a tty - this is not necessarily so as demonstrated by GitHub Actions. It would also be a problem if you were redirecting stdout of the script elsewhere (a log file for instance).

What you want to pass to tee is what was stdout before the process substitution (the `$(...)` bit) - process substitution takes stdout in order to capture the output. Bash and other shells have the ability to manipulate file descriptors for your use case:

```
exec 3>&1  # Open FD 3 as a duplicate of stdout (fd 1)
# Run ./build.sh but make sure it does not have FD 3 open and tee to FD 3
VARIABLE=$(./build.sh 3>&- | tee /dev/fd/3)
exec 3>&-  # Close FD 3
```

Doing it this way allows the stdout of the script to be manipulated outside the script (redirecting to a logger, or /dev/null, etc), preserving the correct behaviour WRT stdout.

Comment: Would I be able to simply tee to stdout or stderror as recommended below ? Or I would need to take this path ?

Also I have `set -e -o pipefail` set, if the command fails and exits will exec will be closed properly ?

Comment: @TorqueNoFriction You can tee to stderr if that's what you want. My answer is how you tee to stdout, since the command substitution alters stdout so it can capture the output. Exiting early will not be a problem. When a process exits, all its files are closed.

Comment: @camh BEST ANSWER EVER

Comment: @camh Using this way, the output before this section is lost, if the entire script is redirected to a file. For example, a [test.sh](https://pastebin.com/mqmEjEfT) has `echo "hello 1"

exec 3>&1  # Open FD 3 as a duplicate of stdout (fd 1)
# Run ./build.sh but make sure it does not have FD 3 open and tee to FD 3
VARIABLE=$(echo "hello 2" 3>&- | tee /dev/fd/3)
exec 3>&-  # Close FD 3

echo "hello 3"` , though `/bin/bash test.sh` gives all three, but `/bin/bash test.sh > test.log` gives only two. Could you help to suggest what is the cause and how to fix ?